# How to implement just some basic keywords highlighting in text editor?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, syntax-highlighting, text-editor

I'm a novice programmer trying to learn plug-in development. I'd like to upgrade the sample XML editor so that some words like "cat", "dog", "hamster", "rabbit" and "bird" would be highlighted when it appears in an XML file (it's just for learning purpose). Can anyone give me some implementation tips or suggestions? I am clueless.. (But I am carrying out my research on this as well, I'm not being lazy. You have my word.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: The example XML editor splits the document in to 'comments', 'tags' and default text. Which of these partitions do you want to detect the words in?

Answer (score 1):

You can detect words in the plain text part of the XML by modifying the sample XML editor as follows.

We can use the provided `WordRule` class to detect the words. The `XMLScanner` class which scans the plain text needs to be updated to include the word rule:

```java
public XMLScanner(final ColorManager manager)
{
  IToken procInstr = new Token(new TextAttribute(manager.getColor(IXMLColorConstants.PROC_INSTR)));

  WordRule words = new WordRule(new WordDetector());  
  words.addWord("cat", procInstr);
  words.addWord("dog", procInstr);
  // TODO add more words here

  IRule [] rules = new IRule [] {
      // Add rule for processing instructions
      new SingleLineRule("<?", "?>", procInstr),
      // Add generic whitespace rule.
      new WhitespaceRule(new XMLWhitespaceDetector()),
      // Words rules
      words
      };

  setRules(rules);
}
```

I have used the existing processing instruction token here to reduce the amount of new code, but you should define a new color and use a new token.

The `WordRule` constructor requires an `IWordDetector` class, we can use a very simple detector here:

```java
class WordDetector implements IWordDetector
{
  @Override
  public boolean isWordStart(final char c)
  {
    return Character.isLetter(c);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isWordPart(final char c)
  {
    return Character.isLetter(c);
  }
}
```

This is just accepting letters in words.

Comment: Thank you, sir. It is very kind of you indeed to help me out. Sorry for the late reply.